# Updating List with MultiSelectComboBox

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm using the code from http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/1a81c5/multi-select-combobox-in-wpf/ and it works fine. One addition i'm trying to make is triggering an action upon SelectionChanged.

I've tried

```
<src:MultiSelectComboBox  ItemsSource="{Binding TargetGroups}" 
                          SelectedItems="{Binding SelectedTargetGroups, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                          cal:Message.Attach="[Event SelectionChanged]=[Action Filter()]"
                          HorizontalAlignment="Left">
</src:MultiSelectComboBox>
```

But that doesn't ever fire.
I've also added Filter() to SelectedTargetGroups but it doesn't get notified upon selection changes.

```
private Dictionary<string, object> _selectedTargetGroups 
public Dictionary<string, object> SelectedTargetGroups
{
    get { return _selectedTargetGroups; }
    set
    {
        _selectedTargetGroups = value;
        Filter();
        OnPropertyChanged("SelectedTargetGroups");
    }
}
```

May I ask how do I get Filter() to fire?

Comment: Are you expecting that the dictionary will be replace with a new dictionary, or that items will be added to the dictionary? Your code as it stands now will raise the OnPropertyChanged event whenever an entirely new dictionary istannce is assigned to SelectedTargetGroups.

Comment: Items to be added to the dictionary, When I set break points SelectedTargetGRoups never fire when I Select items from the MultiSelectComboBox

Answer (score 0):

It looks like an issue in the 3rd party code you are using. `MultiSelectComboBox.SetSelectedItems()` only seems to create a dictionary the first time. Because dictionaries don't implement INotifyCollectionChanged, you can't see individual updates; you'll only see the update from that very first item. Instead, you probably want to change that code to:

```
    private void SetSelectedItems()
    {
        var selectedItems = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        foreach (Node node in _nodeList)
        {
            if (node.IsSelected && node.Title != "All")
            {
                if (this.ItemsSource.Count > 0)

                    selectedItems.Add(node.Title, this.ItemsSource[node.Title]);
            }
        }
        // this should now result in a call to the SelectedTargetGroups setter you have
        SelectedItems = selectedItems;
    }
```

Comment: Hi NextInLine I definitely think you were on the right path but it still didn't notify the changes =(

Comment: Well, if this problem exists in that code, then I suspect there are others as well. Have you confirmed with breakpoints that you are hitting the "new Dictionary" line above?